# error in OpenGL glutKeyboardFunc

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

I'm trying to use glutKeyboardFunc in OpenGL. But when I use this function in main it's giving me an error that `No matching function for call to 'glutKeyboardFunc'`. Why is it so?

```
#include<GLUT/glut.h>
#include<OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

static void display(){
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.6, 1, 0.4);
    glFlush();
}

void mykeypressed(char key, int x,int y){

}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(300, 300);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("ps4_1");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(mykeypressed);
    glutTimerFunc(10000, exit, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The signature of [`glutKeyboardFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node49.html) is

```
void glutKeyboardFunc(void (*func)(unsigned char key, int x, int y));
//                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

Your `mykeypressed()`'s first parameter is a `char`, not `unsigned char`. The two types are different.